# MERN app crasing in the heroku server No errors while deploying

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, mern

My heroku app built successfully but recieves an application error and the logs files
is returning H10 error.

```js
invalid ELF header
'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
2022-05-17T11:16:03.131360+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
 at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
```

These are the main errors I am receiving.
Snippet of the entire error given below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5Jia.png)

Comment: is your node_modules built on deploy with Heroku or are you pre-building it elsewhere?

Comment: @The_flash I removed the node_modules and then deployed it on heroku . I actually followed a video where I was asked to remove it as heroku will add dependencies on its own